# TcpClient hangs

Tags: c#, stream, tcpclient, networkstream

I am working on a simple Client to send data to a server at my office. I tested the code locally on my computer using a server called TCPServer, I connect, send data, receive reply, disconnect, send again, rinse and repeat, it all works perfectly, but when I connect to office and do the same thing it connects fine, I can connect/disconnect forever, but when I send data it just hangs. Nothing is received in the log at the office. I can't send a single byte there.

Seems like a firewall issue doesn't it.

But I can run an older program I wrote years ago in Delphi (pascal), and it connects and sends the same data over without issue, same port, everything, so the problem is not a firewall issue. Thoughts on this? Here is the basic code layout.

Connect Button
Disconnect Button
Send Button

**At the top of the class I declare the TcpClient Variable**

```
    public TcpClient m_client = new TcpClient();
```

**In the _Click for Connect Button and Disconnect Button I have code to connect to server and set some indicators etc**

```
    private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string address = FixIP(IPAddressMaskedTextBox.Text);
        int Port = Convert.ToInt32(PortNumberMaskedTextBox.Text);

        Control control = (Control)sender;
        String name = control.Name;
        try
        {
            switch (name)
            {
                case ("ConnectButton"):
                    //Connect to server
                    connect(address, Port);
                    if (m_client.Connected)
                    {
                        SingleConnectionRichTextBox.Clear();

                        ConnectedLightButton.BackColor = Color.Lime;
                        SingleConnectionRichTextBox.Text += "Connected at IP " + address + " and Port " + Port.ToString() + "\r\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case ("DisconnectButton"):
                    if (m_client.Connected)
                    {
                        SingleConnectionRichTextBox.Text += "Connection Terminated\r\n";
                        ConnectedLightButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        m_client.Client.Disconnect(false);
                        m_client = new TcpClient();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void connect(string address, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!m_client.Connected)
            {
                ConnectedLightButton.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                SingleConnectionRichTextBox.Text += "Attempting to Connect...\r\n";
                m_client.Connect(address, port);
            }
            else
            {
                SingleConnectionRichTextBox.Text += "Connection Failed...\r\n";
                ConnectedLightButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
                throw new Exception("Connect: Already connected\r\n");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**The Send button has it's own event, mostly because when connecting to office it can take a minute for sockets to be created etc.**

```
    private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (m_client.Connected)
            {
                string completeString = "";

                for (int cnt = 0; cnt < SingleSendRichTextBox.Lines.Count() - 1; cnt++)
                {
                    string aLine = Regex.Replace(SingleSendRichTextBox.Lines[cnt], @"\e\[(\d+;)*(\d+)?[ABCDHJKfmsu]", "");

                    if (cnt == 0)
                    {
                        //First line gets Start Block, plus a CR on end
                        aLine = (char)0x0B + aLine + (char)0x0D;
                    }
                    else if (cnt == (SingleSendRichTextBox.Lines.Count() -1))
                    {
                        //Last line gets CR + End Block + CR on end
                        aLine += (char)0x0D + (char)0x1C + (char)0x0D;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //All middle lines get CR on end
                        aLine += (char)0x0D;
                    }

                    //MessageBox.Show("Sending line# " + cnt.ToString() + " = " + aLine);
                    completeString += aLine;
                }
                Byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(completeString);
                WriteBytes(data);
                ReadAllBytes();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing is connected currently...");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void WriteBytes(Byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((m_client.Connected)&&(data.Count() > 0))
            {
                // Get access to network stream
                NetworkStream stm = m_client.GetStream();

                stm.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stm.Flush();

                //MessageBox.Show("Data Sent, length = " + data.Length.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Either we are not connected, or there is no data to send!!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void ReadAllBytes()
    {
        try
        {
            // Buffer to store the response bytes.
            Byte[] readdata = new Byte[256];

            // String to store the response ASCII representation.
            String responseData = String.Empty;

            NetworkStream stm = m_client.GetStream();

            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            Int32 bytes = stm.Read(readdata, 0, readdata.Length);
            responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readdata, 0, bytes);
            SingleReplyRichTextBox.Text += responseData + "\r\n";
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Does anything in here raise a red flag that is obvious? I tried Stream VS NetworkStream. I tried turning off the Reply listener. I took this code and combined it all into one function, and moved the TcpClient creation over to a different Class as static so I could create it in each function, but while all of these worked fine locally, nothing works connecting to office. It won't send a single byte. I set m_client as static at the top too, works fine locally, not to office.

Is GetStream failing maybe? or its sending the data on a different socket?

Comment: Where does it hang? On `stm.Write(data, 0, data.Length);`?

Comment: It hangs after stm.Flush(). I put a dialog in there to confirm it makes it past that point and it does. Length has a value.

Comment: Turns out there is a bit of a bug related to +=. In my code I was assigning End Block control chars to the end of a string using aLine += (char)0x0D + (char)0x1C + (char)0x0D; But after carefully looking at the string in the WatchList I noticed those characters were not being added. I had to change it to aLine = aLine + (char)0x0D + (char)0x1C + (char)0x0D; It was then working at the office.

Answer (score 0):

use a Task and cancellation token to cancel the task. Don't init a "new" TCPclient. In the background the TCPclient will be not closed (socket-timeout of .net)
Use try catches to see the exception and add the log to the conversation to make it more clear pls